# display file in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to display a textfile from a server location in the network but does not work?

```
  public ActionResult ShowFile()
    {
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\some unc path\\TextFile1.txt");

        var stream = new StreamReader(filepath);
        return File(stream.ReadToEnd(), "text/plain");

    }
```

Comment: Your backslashes are under-escaped.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is `Server.MapPath("\\some unc path\\TextFile1.txt");` The file isn't located in your server document directory, so the mapping will fail. You have an absolute path, so use this in your `StreamReader` or give it directly to the `File()` method.

Also your path is incorrect. See the other post.

Comment: I didn't notice that.  There are also a bunch of other problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` method takes a stream or filename; you're trying to pass it the file contents.
Change it to

```
return File(@"\\some unc path\TextFile1.txt", "text/plain");
```